# algorithm to find most realistic market price average in dataset

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

### What I have:

- users are selling foobars on an auction site.
- each foobar is identical.
- price of foobar determined by user.
- i will be scrapping each price listing to form a data set that looks like:
  $prices = ('foobar' => [12.34, 15.22, 14.18, 20.55, 9.50]);

### What I need:

- to find a realistic average market price for each day, week, month.

### Problems I face:

- Outlier rejection implimentations are not proving to work very well because the data is biased.
- It is extremely unlikely that a user will commit their auction to way below average market price becuase it can not be undone. Even if it is way below market price, this instance will happen so infrequently that the overall average will not be affected. However, users that will try to drive their prices up is much more likely and will happen frequently enough to affect the realistic average marketplace value.

### What I think I'm going to do about it:

```
Daniel Collicott:
```

> if I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the optimal
>   selling value of an item. (or are you trying to calculate the real
>   value??)
>
> Sellers are quite naturally gaming (e.g. ebay), trying to maximize
>   their profits.
>
> For this reason, I'd would avoid average/SD approaches: they are too
>   sensitive to outliers created by particular selling tactics.
>
> Game-theory-wise, I think clever sellers would estimate the highest
>   likely selling price (maximal profits) by researching their
>   competitors and their historical sales output: to find the sweet spot.
>
> For this reason I would record a histogram of historical prices over
>   all sellers and look at the distribution of prices, using something
>   approaching the mode to determine the optimal price i.e. the most
>   common sale price. Better still, I would weigh prices by the profit
>   (proportional to historical sales volume) of each individual seller.
>
> I suspect this would be nearer to your optimal market value; if you
>   are looking for the real market value then comment below or contact me
>   at my machine learning firm

### Questions I have:

- A more detailed explanation for the things refered to in @Daniel Collicott's post:

  --> optimal selling value
  --> real selling value
  --> algorithms for both

Comment: What would you want your algorithm to do in the last two examples?

Comment: At the most fundamental level, you are simply looking for the median of the dataset. Is there other information you have that would give more insight to a small dataset? If not, there's nothing you can do mathematically speaking.

Comment: Incidentally, you're talking about [outlier rejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers).

Comment: In your last example, how do you know that it isn't the `12.34` and `15.66` that are the unreasonable outliers?

Comment: @sarnold Once a user confirms their auction post, they are commited to it. It is extremely unlikely that a user will run down prices rather than run them up.

Comment: @Dan: Don't be so sure. Perhaps their product is made of sawdust or papier machee -- they may be underselling the competition by dint of being unscrupulous. (Frequently seen on Craigslist; 64GB iPad for only $129! What a deal!)

Comment: @sarnold This is not the case.

Comment: @Dan: Aha; excellent news for you, then. :) Spotting outliers on only one end of the spectrum may be an easier problem.

Comment: @sarnold: Mind sharing your insight? =)

Comment: @sarnold: Regarding your first comment, I would also ask why the outlier in the second example is `102.55` and not `12.34`, that looks even more ambiguous to me since the gap between the values is much higher.

Comment: @Alix: only that knowing outliers will be high allows the stddev calculation to be repeated multiple times including and excluding higher values and stopping when the stddev is brought within some lower range. (It's even not too expensive to compute a new stddev from some previous state and "the new value", so it shouldn't be too expensive.) Or, perhaps, only exclude prices more than avg + 2*std dev, and leave alone elements less than avg - 2*std dev. Options!

Comment: What should `(12.34, 102.55, 134.66, 139.49)` return?

Comment: @AlixAxel It would need to return 12.34. It is extremely unlikely that a user will commit their auction to way below average market price becuase it can not be undone. Even if it is way below market price, this instance will happen so infrequently that the overall average will not be affected. However, users that will try to drive their prices up is much more likely and will happen frequently enough to affect the realistic average marketplace value.

Comment: @DanKanze: Weird, since in that case the outlier is `12.34`... Well, I'll let someone else have a go at it, I'm curious to see other implementations as well.

Comment: @DanKanze: Your specifications seem a bit subjective. If you set your upper threshold to `harmonicMean + standardDeviation` it'll pass all the examples you gave so far, but for sets like `(12.34, 15.66)` it will only return `12.34`, which I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, it *seems* wrong to me at least.

Comment: @DanKanze: I corrected your code, but `asort()` orders in ASC order and in the code comment you say you want the smaller values tho you use `array_pop` which is confusing... Remove the `* -1` in `array_slice` if what you want is `array_shift` behavior.

Comment: @DanKanze: Also, what you're doing looks pretty much like computing the global mean average of the individual hours (sort of) median.

Comment: @AlixAxel yea I mean I just wrote that out quickly to give a general idea. But thanks. Yea the global mean average is really a wierd thing. You need to keep in mind that the data set is biased. What I'm looking for the most realistic way to represent biased data. This is jsut my "one" idea... I have a couple other appraoches I am considering, I may update this post to include those as well soon.

Comment: @Dan: I believe that any answer to your question is nonsensical as long as you haven't defined what you want. The term "realistic average market price" is just too open. The most realistic figure I can think of is the total sales ($) over the number of sold items. But we have no clue if that is what you are looking for, and what you need it for...

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you read my question it becomes clear what a realistic average market price is, and what difficulties there are in achieving it. Specifically, the dataset in a competitive market place is biased and doesn't realistically represent the "real" or "optimal" selling value. Because of this, standard averaging to which you refer ("total sales ($) over the number of sold items") is an inferior low level approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust As for ("what you are looking for, and what you need it for") refer to my ("what i need", "questions i have") sections clearly bolded...

Comment: If you need the average real market value, why don't you simply get the average of *sold* items? I mean, an item is worth what the market pays for it, not what sellers price it at, right?

Comment: @Gustav Bertram Like most auction sites, the history of sold items is non-disclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is normalise your dataset - i.e. to converge on a set that that reflects the mean then you could use the [Kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) and [Skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) to characterise the structure of your dataset to help identify outliers - (compute the metrics for each point using the rest of the dataset aim to minimise Kurtois and preserve the tendancy of the Skewness - reject extreme values and repeat until excluding a value doesn't significantly change metrics).

But your problem is a bit more interesting:

Let me see if I've got this right: You have an imperfect understanding of the foobar market, but you have access to limited concrete information about it.

You want to use your limited dataset to predict hidden information about the market.

You need the [Bayesian Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average) (see also [Bayesian Inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Examples)).

Let's assume you have 1000 prices per day;

For each day, compute: mean, mode, median, stdev, kurtosis and skewness - this gives a handle of the shape of the market:

- mean & median will show how prices are moving
- mode & stdev will show how mature the market is (mature markets should have lower
  stdev)
- kurtosis will show price elasticity - low values are
  elastic, higher are more plastic - also relates to maturity
- skewness will show trends in demand - a long tail to the left indicates bargin hunters, a tail to the right indicates willingness to pay higher prices

Comparing daily values will enable you to measure the health of the market.

Once you have a few weeks worth of trend data (it gets better over time) you can start testing for true prices.

1. In the first instance take an educated guess at the true price on the first day of your dataset.
2. Compute a Bayesian average price for the market using a skew weighted sample of prices, but sample no more than 80% / stddev^2 of the daily set
3. This now becomes your true price.
4. Repeating 2 - 4 for each day should give you a slowly moving price.

If the true prices are jumping around then either the sample size is too small or the market isn't functioning properly (i.e. some of the participants are paying above the value, selling below value, supply is restricted, purchase price isn't related to value, etc).

I've had a go modelling used car prices (they're not homogenous) but I did get some reasonable convergence - +/- 10% but that was on a limited dataset. It would also seem to work with house prices, not commodities or football scores.

It's never going to give you a definitive predictive answer, especially not in an auction environment - but it should get you a lot closer to the true price than an arithmetic mean would.

Comment: This looks like what I want. I am very curious to see how this will handle against a large dataset. I will be avidly waiting for your implimentation.

Answer (score 7):

Your first problem pretty straightforward using the **average** and the **standard deviation**:

```
$prices = array
(
    'bar' => array(12.34, 102.55),
    'foo' => array(12.34, 15.66, 102.55, 134.66),
    'foobar' => array(12.34, 15.22, 14.18, 20.55, 99.50, 15.88, 16.99, 102.55),
);

foreach ($prices as $item => $bids)
{
    $average = call_user_func_array('Average', $bids);
    $standardDeviation = call_user_func_array('standardDeviation', $bids);

    foreach ($bids as $key => $bid)
    {
        if (($bid < ($average - $standardDeviation)) || ($bid > ($average + $standardDeviation)))
        {
            unset($bids[$key]);
        }
    }

    $prices[$item] = $bids;
}

print_r($prices);
```

Basically you just need to remove bids lower than `avg - stDev` or higher than `avg + stDev`.

---

And the actual functions (ported from [my framework](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Math.php)):

```
function Average()
{
    if (count($arguments = func_get_args()) > 0)
    {
        return array_sum($arguments) / count($arguments);
    }

    return 0;
}

function standardDeviation()
{
    if (count($arguments = func_get_args()) > 0)
    {
        $result = call_user_func_array('Average', $arguments);

        foreach ($arguments as $key => $value)
        {
            $arguments[$key] = pow($value - $result, 2);
        }

        return sqrt(call_user_func_array('Average', $arguments));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output ([demo](http://codepad.org/PZVNE9Td)):

```
Array
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
            [1] => 102.55
        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [1] => 15.66
            [2] => 102.55
        )

    [foobar] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
            [1] => 15.22
            [2] => 14.18
            [3] => 20.55
            [5] => 15.88
            [6] => 16.99
        )
)
```

Comment: You're treating anything outside 1-sigma as an outlier?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, after I answered I realized that this approach doesn't solve the OP 2nd and 3rd problems, so I edited accordingly.

Comment: @AlixAxel I'm sorry I didn't include this in my post but in 2nd and 3rd cases, I would assume group of like elements with smallest average. So 'foo' => array(12.34, 15.66, 102.55, 134.66) would need to return 12.34 and 15.66.

Comment: @DanKanze: Yeah, I'm sorry too, I just realized that after posting. I've an idea to get the 3rd case right, but the second one baffles me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a lot of struggling here is a solution that seems to work regardless of how extreme (or not) are **max** the outliers. Bare in mind that my math knowledge is pretty raw so take this with a grain of salt.

```
$prices = array
(
    'baz' => array(12.34, 15.66),
    'bar' => array(12.34, 102.55),
    'foo' => array(12.34, 15.66, 102.55, 134.66),
    'foobar' => array(12.34, 15.22, 14.18, 20.55, 99.50, 15.88, 16.99, 102.55),
);

foreach ($prices as $item => $bids)
{
    $average = average($bids);
    $standardDeviation = standardDeviation($bids);

    foreach ($bids as $key => $bid)
    {
        if ($bid > ($average + ($average - $standardDeviation)))
        {
            unset($bids[$key]);
        }
    }

    $prices[$item] = $bids;
}

print_r($prices);

function average($arguments)
{
    if (count($arguments) > 0)
    {
        return array_sum($arguments) / count($arguments);
    }

    return 0;
}

function standardDeviation($arguments)
{
    if (count($arguments) > 0)
    {
        $result = Average($arguments);

        foreach ($arguments as $key => $value)
        {
            $arguments[$key] = pow($value - $result, 2);
        }

        return sqrt(Average($arguments));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output ([demo](http://codepad.org/1kWrfUyZ)):

```
Array
(
    [baz] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
            [1] => 15.66
        )

    [bar] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
        )

    [foo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
            [1] => 15.66
        )

    [foobar] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.34
            [1] => 15.22
            [2] => 14.18
            [3] => 20.55
            [5] => 15.88
            [6] => 16.99
        )
)
```

Comment: I changed question slightly. Hopefully I am more clear this time. Added a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Dan, reading your comments I'm starting to think what you want can be achieved very simply. This is in C# but it is so simple it should be easy to understand:

```
const double reasonable_price_range = 1.5;
List<double> prices = new List<double> { 50.00, 51.00, 52.00, 100.00, 101.00, 102.00, 150.00, 151.00, 152.00 };
double min = prices.Min();
var reasonable_prices = (from p in prices where p <= min * reasonable_price_range select p).ToList();
```

Discard all numbers which are larger than the *smallest* price by a certain percentage (percentage is the best measure here IMO), then return the rest.

This should work for all your examples. The 1.5 constant is arbitrary and should probably be higher (the question is, if we know price X is reasonable, how high can the price go and still be considered reasonable?). However, this relies on there not being even a single low outlier - the lowest price on the list must be a reasonable one.

Of course, min * constant is not necessarily the optimal decision function, but if we can rely on the min never being an outlier, the problem becomes much simpler, as instead of grouping elements we can compare them to the minimum element in some way.

Comment: I changed question slightly. Hopefully I am more clear this time. Added a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the *optimal* selling value of an item. (or are you trying to calculate the *real* value??)

Sellers are quite naturally gaming (e.g. ebay), trying to maximize their profits.

For this reason, I'd would avoid average/SD approaches: they are too sensitive to outliers created by particular selling tactics.

Game-theory-wise, I think clever sellers would estimate the highest likely selling price (maximal profits) by researching their competitors and their historical sales output: to find the sweet spot.

For this reason I would record a histogram of historical prices over all sellers and look at the distribution of prices, using something approaching the mode to determine the *optimal* price i.e. the most common sale price. Better still, I would weigh prices by the profit (proportional to historical sales volume) of each individual seller.

I suspect this would be nearer to your *optimal* market value; if you are looking for the *real* market value then comment below or contact me at my [machine learning](http://www.minimalistic.eu/) firm

Comment: Optimal market value sounds very close to what I want. Could you go into more detail about what "real" market value is? I don't quite understand the difference.

Comment: I would define the optimum market value as the selling price that maximises the total sales profit (over a given time window); the 'real' value would be defined as the intrinsic worth of the goods i.e. roughly what it takes to produces the goods (materials and labour) but ignoring any additional perceived value e.g. that created by marketing or market speculation and the associated costs of distorting this intrinsic value e.g. advertising & distribution models.

Comment: Given that you are looking for the optimum market value, you need to estimate the intrinsic value of the goods in order to calculate the per-item profit at a given price point e.g.  a working definition of 'real' value might be calculated by interpolating wholesale prices at different volumes-price breaks.

Comment: The optimum market value will then maximise the function (profit per item)*(sales volume), bearing in mind that both components are a function of the selling and potentially, the minimum asking price.
Then if I were selling items, I would start by offering something near to the estimated mode and then repeatedly refine this value using machine learning to maximise the total sales profit.